# Dividing $x^3+2$ by $2x^2+3x+4$ in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory

Pinter, in his book "A book of Abstract Algebra" asks the reader to divide $x^3+2$ by $2x^2+3x+4$ in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$. But I do not see how it can be done. Suppose that it could be done. Then there would exist polynomials $px+q$ and $p'x+q'$ in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ such that 
$$ x^3+2=(px+q)(2x^2+3x+4)+(p'x+q')$$

This would imply that $2p=1$ but there is no $p \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $2p=1$. Thus, it is not possible to do the usual euclidean division.
 **Is this question incorrect or am I going wrong somewhere?**

[image: Problem number 3]

Comment: LIkely it is a typo, i.e. $\Bbb Z[x]\,$ should be some $\,\Bbb Z_n[x]\,$ (else it is poor exposition).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is correct, and your answer is correct as well. It is simply not possible to do that division in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$.

Comment: If there is no typo and the queston really intends one to  "find *the* quotient and remainder* that does not exist, then the question is so poorly worded that it will likely often prove misleading (as it did for the OP). It is not clear that was the "correct" intention ($\Bbb Z[x]$ may well be a typo for some other $\Bbb Z_n[x])\ \ $

Comment: @BillDubuque I agree with you on the fact that the question is misleading. Maybe I should have said ini my answer that the question is licit and the answer is that the quotient and the remainder do not exist.